# Pass django model elemts to javascript file

Tags: javascript, django

Is it possible to pass model elements directly to a java script file? I am making a custom plugin , the plugin is in a plugins folder. I have it completed but i need to pass a list of model objects into it. I have a few ideas on how i could hack the elements in via a template file but id prefer if there was a function i could call from directly within the java script file to load the elements. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you should use Ajax and request the models to the server.
Another alternative is to serve your javascript file with django and populate it like you would with a template